# Ruby Chapter 8 tutorial partial file not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl - Chapter 8 - Rails 3

In the file new.html.erb I have:

```
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
```

I created the file app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb

When I run the test: bundle exec rspec spec/requests/users_spec.rb I get the following error messages:

Failures:

1. Users signup failure should not make a new user

   ```
   Failure/Error: visit signup_path
   ActionView::Template::Error:
     Missing partial shared/error_messages with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "/Users/username/rails_projects/my_sample_app/app/views"
   ```
2. Users signup success should make a new user

   ```
   Failure/Error: visit signup_path
   ActionView::Template::Error:
     Missing partial shared/error_messages with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "/Users/username/rails_projects/my_sample_app/app/views"
   ```

Comment: what if you replace with `<%= render '/shared/error_messages' %>`

Comment: That didn't work. I am using AptanaStudio3 as my editor and as soon as I saved the file the following error occurred: /Aptana Studio 3/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/84/1/.cp/bundles/rails.ruble/commands/content_assist.rb:7)
 at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(org/jruby/RubyProc.java:268) Still tried running rspec anyway and got the same error

Comment: really weird, no other idea then

Answer (score 1):

Thanks apneadiving. When I went to the folder app/views/shared and did an ls command it showed the file there. However, when I tried to cat the file it returned file not found. Doing an ls -al showed the file had a @ for extra attributes. I loaded the file in my editor and saved it under another name. Then recreated the original file and removed the old file. Everything worked then.