# Rails: Missing partial Ruby Chapter 8 tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl - Chapter 8 - Rails 3
I use rails 3.1
In the file new.html.erb I have:

```
<h1>Sign up</h1>
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
```

Trying to visit http://localhost:3000/signup, it gives me the following message:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate in Users#new

Missing partial /shared/error_messages with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee], 
:formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in:
* "/Users/macbook/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views"
```

I have googled around but could not find this answer. The same question was posted a while ago at:
[Ruby Chapter 8 tutorial partial file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471558/ruby-chapter-8-tutorial-partial-file-not-found)

What I tried:
-putting a / in front of shared
- putting :partial => after render
-putting :target => @user

If I don't put it into the shared folder, it works. Is there a different way to do this in rails 3.1.3? Please let me know because I've spent so much time trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 9):

If you say;

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
```

it will look for a partial named `shared/error_messages` in the `app/views/#{controller_name}`

ie. if you're in the `users#signup` action, it will expect to find `app/views/users/shared/error_messages`

If in fact you mean `app/views/shared/error_messages`
then you should say the following.

```
<%= render '/shared/error_messages' %>
```

That's just the only way to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: You're a genious! Thanks a lot! I hope other people will see this answer as well, cause I was searching forever and could not find it. For anyone who's confused, I just changed the part above to 

<%= render "users/shared/error_messages"%>

Answer (score 8):

Did you name the file correctly (with the underscore)? That was my problem...

**error_messages.html.erb**

should be

**_error_messages.html.erb**

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had named the shared folder **Shared** instead of **shared**.
Also, check that the partial starts with underscore.

Answer (score 1):

even stranger, I named mine _clinicaltrails.html.erb instead of _clinicaltrial.html.erb; riddle me that why making it singular worked, but thought I would leave my solution here too for frustrated newbs people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same challenge when working on a Rails 6 application.

I had defined my **partials** in a directory named `shared` inside the `app/views` directory.

And then I defined the partials in the `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` file like this:

```
<%= render partial: '_shared/mobile_header' %>
```

I had to re-define it this way:

```
<%= render partial: '/shared/mobile_header' %>
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**